# Generate minimal regex from long list of matches

Tags: java, regex

I have a long list of url-paths to a website (~180000). In my current project I want to filter out all incoming paths whose prefixes match one of those entries.

The data is very homogeneous: 80% of entries are something like `"/abc/<id1>.<id2>/<id3>"`. Even the rest can be grouped perfectly into regexes, but manually doing that for 180k entries isn't worth it.

Is there an automatic solution (for Java) to generate minimal regexes from that list?

In CS theory one could build a DFA from all entries and try minimizing it, and translate the result into a regex. But is there an existing library supplying that functionality?

I will also accept any library matching a reasonable superset of the list (so even if only [0-8]* appears for `id1` inside the samples, [0-9]* would be fine as a regex too).

Comment: There is an online regular expression generator on [text2re.com](http://txt2re.com/) where you can input some text you want to use a regular expression on, click on what you want to match, and it’ll generate the regular expression for you.

Answer (score 0):

If I read correctly, then you should be able to just iterate over the URLs and check the prefix:

```
List<String> keep = new ArrayList<>();

for (String url : urls) {
    if (url.matches("^/abc/<id1>.<id2>/<id3>.*")) {
        keep.add(url);
    }
}
```